# Python3: How to generate a pseudo-random sequence per object?

Tags: python, random, synchronization, generator, python-3.5

I have a test project where some entity can fire a bullet, and depending on the hit orientation and some random values, it can either impact or be deflected.

When running offline, its rather easy to generate random numbers on the go in order to tell if a shot should ricochet or not, as with `random.randint()` or `random.random()`.

But I'm looking to broadcast the firing event via UDP, so that other clients can display the same entities/projectiles on their screen.

Projectiles are very high velocity, so I can't wait for the server to tell me the past location and just use that (I could correct the trajectory though). The main idea is to receive the `fire` call from the remote entity, get some values such as `position, velocity, randseed`.

My problem is how do I use seeds for each entity ?

Say I have 10 bullets at once on my screen, each with its own pseudo-random seed, I want bullets to generate their own pseudo sequence, as they would on one side of the network or another.

> Example:
>
> ```
> class Bullet(object):
>     def __init__(self, pos, v, seed):
>         self.randgen = InstanciableGenerator(seed)
>         # ...
>
>     def hit(self, pos, ...):
>         currentRandom = self.randgen.get()
>         # ...
> ```
>
> So that each instance has its own random sequence, not one shared by the `random.seed()` across each `random.random()` calls.

## How to generate distinct pseudo-random sequences ?

If it were to be a bad idea, what would be the best approach to broadcast a firing event, so that it is somewhat sync with all clients + server ?

PS: The server has full authority, the sync is for display purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `random.Random` class, e.g.:

```
self.randgen = random.Random(seed)
```

Then calls to `self.randgen.random()` (or `.randint(<int>)`) will be local to your instance.

Alternatively, you can create a wrapper which uses `self.state = random.getstate()` and then `random.setstate(self.state)` before each call to `random.random()`

Comment: Well, that was quick... It happens that I did not find this `Random` object in the `random`'s documentation... But after you mentionned it, it was indeed mentionned in the docucementation, although in some paragraph where the object is considered "hidden". My bad. Thanks a lot !